# Apply same CSS value to multiple items in jQuery

Tags: jquery, collections

I am trying to apply the same css property "top" to multiple items but having trouble with the syntax. The below code only the 1st element gets the CSS property applied not the 2nd.

```
let navItems = $this.find(".swiper-button-next", ".swiper-button-prev").css('top', h);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put both selectors in the same selector string, not separate arguments.

```
let navItems = $this.find(".swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev").css('top', h);
```